# Qual melhor forma de trabalhar/armazenar arquivos em base64 C# + SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, base64

Estou consumindo uma API externa, e no retorno dela tenho um arquivo PDF em formato `base64`, gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de trabalhar/armazenar esse tipo de dado no banco de dados `SqlServer` + `C#`.

> Minha dúvida é:

1 - Devo armazenar o retorno em `base64` criando um campo text no `sql-server` (sei que não é a melhor forma, pois campos text é custoso para o banco de dados).

2 - Devo criar um campo no formato `varbinary(max)` e converter essa string `base64` para `byte[]` ?

Comment: Meu caro, a outra pergunta que fiz você marcou como pendente, por isso reabri outra e bem detalhada. O Que posso fazer pra publicar uma ou outra pergunta?

Comment: acredito que você quer saber qual a melhor pratica para isso né? olha ja fiz algo parecido com imagem, e não deu muito certo o banco ficou grande demais! Dependendo do tamanho do arquivo será enorme o texto, portanto aconselho você ler o base64 retornado pela api e salvar no disco do servidor ou em uma nuvem e no banco de dados você salva apenas o local e nome do arquivo!

Comment: @Lodi, e se eu transformar esse base64 em array de bytes e persistir num campo varbinary(max) ? porque assim, eu preciso no momento guardar por um tempo isso em base64 e depois que meu cadastro for totalmente concluído irei guardar em uma storage e apagar esses registros do banco de dados deixando apenas a referencia do caminho do arquivo.

Comment: Agora ja não é mais uma duvida, pois daria para fazer de diversas formas, inclusive as formas mencionadas por você! Para mim a melhor forma de se fazer isso é lendo o arquivo do disco local, no banco de dados só o path e informações do arquivo! 
Acredito que assim seria menos custoso para a aplicação, mas fica a seu critério...